# How to update widget dynamically in GTK3 (PyGObject)?

Tags: python, gtk

In this example, I'm trying to add another button (or any widget) every time a button is pressed.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk


class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Button Demo")
        self.hbox = Gtk.HBox()
        self.add(self.hbox)
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click Me")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_clicked)
        self.hbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)

    def on_clicked(self, button):
        print("This prints...")
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Another button")
        self.hbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)  # ... but the new button doesn't appear


win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I have tried `queue_draw()` and other hacks, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `show_all()` method works to update widgets' children. Here is the code with `show_all()` used, and the added line marked accordingly:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk


class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Button Demo")
        self.hbox = Gtk.HBox()
        self.add(self.hbox)
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click Me")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_clicked)
        self.hbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)

    def on_clicked(self, button):
        print("This prints...")
        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Another button")
        self.hbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)
        self.hbox.show_all() ### ADDED LINE


win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

So, calling `self.hbox.show_all()` shows all the children of `self.hbox`.